# Regex on timestamp with optional colon

Tags: regex, regex-group

Hello everyone I need help in making solution in regex I have this regex:

```
/^([0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9]):[0-5][0-9][:]\?$/
```

and as a user I can use `28:30` or `28` or `100:30` or `100` my regex is working fine when I add colon, but when I want to remove colon and simply use `28` or `100` it does not work, please help me.

Comment: Just 2 or 3 digits, possibly followed by : and 2 digits? This one will do: (\d{2,3})(:\d{2})?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the regex

```
\d{2,3}(:[0-5]\d)?
```

see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aAgZ3u/1)

Comment: Note that you could use a non-capturing group to apply the `?` quantifier to the optional part. If both parts need to be retrieved separately, `(\d{2,3})(?::([0-5]\d))?` would be practical, but using a regex without capturing groups and just splitting the result over `:` would be much more efficient.

Comment: with your given answer its working and I made some changes that I need I used ^\d{1,3}:?[0-5][0-9]$ what it is doing when I use simple 100, it works fine and when I use 100 with adding : it shows error until I add the minutes that is what I wanted and the problem is when I use simple two digit value(20) it shows error and it should not do like when we add 100 it does not show error similarly after 100 we use colon it shows error until we add minutes.

Comment: @Aaron your solution worked for me, great for both for help

Comment: @azim Eeeh, my suggestions don't take that into account, and it's not even something you can do with regex (since I suppose you don't want to accept `100:` as a final value either). It should be handled with JS or whatever you use to validate your fields (configure some leniency on the validation)